# Laplace's transform

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $$ x:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{C}^n$$ such that $$|x(t)|\leq Me^{\alpha t}$$ for some constants $M \geq 0$ and $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Then the Laplace transform
$$\mathbb{L(x)(s)}=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}x(t)dt$$ exists and is analytic for $\Re(s)>a$. Show that for $x\in C^1([0,\infty))$ satisfying $$|x(t)|+|\dot x(t)|\leq Me^{\alpha t}$$ we have
$$\mathbb L(\dot x)(s)=sL(x)(s)-x(0)$$ for $\Re(s)>a$. Moreover, I have to show that the Initial Value Problem $$\dot x(t)=Ax(t)+g(t)\quad\text{with}\quad x(0)=x_0$$ is transformed into a linear system of equations by the Laplace transform.

As Artem suggested I am integrating by parts:
$$\mathbb{L(\dot x)(s)}=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}\dot x(t)dt$$ So using integration by parts we have $$\mathbb{L(\dot x)(s)}=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}\dot x(t)dt=e^{-st}x(t)+s\int_0^\infty e^{-st}x(t)dt=e^{-st}x(t)|_{t=0}^{t=\infty}+s\mathbb{L(x)(s)}
=s\mathbb{L(x)(s)}-x_0$$

I'm thinking:
Take the Laplace transformation of both sides of $$\dot x(t)=Ax(t)+g(t)$$
$$\mathbb L ({\dot x(t)})=\mathbb L( {Ax(t)+g(t)})$$
$$s\mathbb L ({x(t)})-x_0=A\mathbb L( {x(t)}+sL(g(t)))$$
$$(sI-A)\mathbb L ({x(t)})=x_0+sL(g(t)))$$
which is a a linear system of equations.

Am I done?

Comment: Hint: integration by parts.

Comment: @Artem I am working on it up. Thank you!

Comment: Here is a [reference](http://faculty.atu.edu/mfinan/4243/section75.pdf) to the method.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Thank you so much, great reference!

Comment: @Klara: You are very welcome.